# Javascript plot 'X' in table from object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a table that consists of dates across the table headers and fruit down the left hand side. What i'm trying to do is get the date and the fruit eaten from a different object called 'eaten' and plot an X in the table row/column that coincides with the day it was consumed.

**HTML**

```
<table class="plan">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><strong>Food</strong></th>
   <th>27/01/2017</th>
   <th>28/01/2017</th>    
   <th>29/01/2017</th>
   <th>30/01/2017</th>
   <th>31/01/2017</th>
   <th>01/02/2017</th>
   <th>02/02/2017</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Apple</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Banana</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Carrot</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Pear</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The food titles are created via javascript from one object 'food', the dates are generated via momentJS and 'eaten' is the object data I want to plot from.

**Javascript**

```
var food = '{"food":[{"Name":"Apple"},{"Name":"Banana"},{"Name":"Carrot"},{"Name":"Pear"}]}';

$.each(JSON.parse(food), function(i, f) {
  var tblRow = "";
  tblRow += "<tr><td>" + f.Name + "</td></tr>";
  $(tblRow).appendTo(".plan tbody");
});

for(i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
  var day = moment().subtract('days', i).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  $('<th>' + day + '</th>').appendTo('.plan thead tr');
};

var eaten = '{"eaten":[{"fields":[{"value":"02/02/2017"},{"value":"Carrot"}]},{"fields":[{"value":"31/01/2017"},{"value":"Pear"}]},{"fields":[{"value":"30/01/2017"},{"value":"Banana"}]},{"fields":[{"value":"29/01/2017"},{"value":"Apple"}]},{"fields":[{"value":"27/01/2017"},{"value":"Apple"}]}]}'
```

What is the best way to go about plotting an X from the eaten object? 
Should I get the cellIndex / rowIndex then compare the html text and plot an X?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we1r1j23/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion (without changing your data schema and trying to not change much of your code logic):

1. parse your JSON once, for further reuse:

   ```
   var eaten = JSON.parse(eatenJSON);
   var food = JSON.parse(foodJSON);
   ```
2. populate a `days` array with your days.

   ```
   var days = [];
   for(i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
       var day = moment().subtract('days', i).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
       days.push(day);
   }
   ```
3. set `data-day` and `data-food` in your `td` element;

   ```
   for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
       tblRow += "<td data-day='" + days[i] + "' data-food='" + f.Name + "'></td>";
   }
   ```
4. iterate over the `eaten` structure, find the elements with correspondent `data-day` and`data-food` and, set their `innerText` with `X`, or whatever you want.

   ```
   /* fill table */
   eaten.eaten.forEach( function(userEaten) {
     var fields = userEaten.fields;
     var day = fields[0].value;
     var food = fields[1].value;
     document.querySelectorAll("td[data-day='" + day + "'][data-food='" + food + "']").forEach(function(td) {
        td.innerText = "X";
     });   
   });
   ```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/5gj4udf6/1/

---

**EDIT:** Updated the fiddle with your new JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/5gj4udf6/2/

Just replaced this line

```
$.each(food, function(i, f) {
```

with:

`food.food.forEach(function(f) {`

Comment: Sorry i got the data schema wrong for 'food'. 
If it's like this:
{
 "food": [{
  "Name": "Member Online Portal"
 }, {
  "Name": "Qinvest Corporate Website"
 }, {
  "Name": "QSuper Public Website"
 }, {
  "Name": "Acurity"
 }, {
  "Name": "Member Online Support Portal"
 }]
}
I'm trying to loop through it like f[i].Name except now the <td data-food=""> changes to every food going along the horizontal cells.

Comment: @Pizdets, please update your question with the updated schema

Comment: i've updated and also fixed the JSFiddle link. Cheers,